# "Error: 'sessionAsSigner' not found" after Firefox updated to ver 28.0

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

Using sessionAsSigner in SSJS which worked fine until Firefox updated itself to version 28.0
Now get this error: "Error: 'sessionAsSigner' not found"

Still works in Internet Explorer 9.0

Anyone else experienced this and/or know how to resolve it?

Comment: a Firefox update could never affect that, SSJs runs on the server. Are you sure that the code isn't running in clientside javascript.

Comment: Sounds strange. Are you getting the error in the exact same nsf when doing the exact same scenario with the exact same user logged on?

Comment: Please, summarize it in answer. Also, list of addons or exact addon that makes trouble could help someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the browser update was a red herring.

If you get this error every time the code has run then you should ensure all design elements are signed with the same ID. Clean (Project -> Clean) the database if errors continue. I have found that sometimes 2 cleans are needed to resolve this (and other strange xPage issues).

However, I found that even after this has been done a user can still get this error randomly. When the user runs the code a second time it usually runs without error.

I would appreciate anyone's insight into why this could occur randomly.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this when My xPage/CustomControl and attached ScriptLibrary are signed with different signers.

Resigning the database with server ID and re-building the application fixed the issue.
'sessionAsSigner' works fine now.